# Suggestion for a multimedia chassis with ATX or mATX mainboard support?

Tags: atx, micro-atx

I want to build a new multimedia system. For this i would like to use some multimedia chassis and put a regular ATX or mATX mainboard inside.

One other limitation of the chassis is that the height cannot exceed 20 cm, because it need to fit inside an existing storage rack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you say multimedia system do you mean a pc to run dvds, stream media to etc?  If so then possibly this case though the psu might be a bit on the small side:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811147098

You could also look at these (I have always liked coolermaster cases though have never actually used their smaller form factor varieties):

http://www.coolermaster.co.uk/product.php?category_id=21&product_id=5942
or
http://www.coolermaster.co.uk/product.php?category_id=3561&product_id=6623

Comment: that's exactly what i'm looking for. Maybe some other guys will post more suggestions.